# How to change the value of SurfaceSlider without calling the ValueChanged event?

Tags: slider

Im working with a MediaElement object and SurfaceSlider object, I use the SurfaceSlider to control the Video position and also want the SurfaceSlider to show the current position of the video, like youtube does.

I use this code to control the position of the video, this function is called when the ValueChanged event of the SurfaceSlider object occurs...

```
private void SeekToMediaPosition(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> args)
{
    int SliderValue = (int)mySurfaceSlider.Value;
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, SliderValue);
    myMediaElement.Position = ts;
}
```

I use this code to show the current position of the video...

```
DispatcherTimer ticks = new DispatcherTimer();

private void Element_MediaOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mySurfaceSlider.Maximum = myMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds;
    ticks.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
    ticks.Tick += ticks_Tick;
    ticks.Start(); 
    myMediaElement.Play();
}

void ticks_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    mySurfaceSlider.Value = myMediaElement.Position.TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

The problem is when the SurfaceSlider value is changed showing the current position of the video, the ValueChanged event is called too, and the position of the video is changed, creating a loop I guess.

Is there any other event to be used when the user changes the SurfaceSlider value, or a way to handle this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Esteban,

I think there are a few things I would try.

1... Increase your TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1) to TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100) or higher.  I don't think your slider needs to be polling your video so continuously.

2... I think you could set a flag in SeekToMediaPosition (SeekInProgress=true) before you set myMediaElement.Position.  Then in  ticks_Tick, if SeekInProgress==true, set SeekInProgress=false and don't set mySurfaceSlider.Value for one timer cycle.

I believe the original version of the code you are using comes from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748248.aspx ... Perhaps there is something that code was doing to prevent your problem that has been omitted from your implementation?

If the slider is jumping around, maybe there is lag between when the user places their finger down on the slider and when they move it (causing SeekToMediaPosition to fire).  What you need to do is detect if the user is currently touching mySurfaceSlider in ticks_Tick (maybe there is a collection of touch points to query for intersection with mySurfaceSlider? Or does mySurfaceSlider have touchdown and touchup events?) In any case, if the user is even TOUCHING mySurfaceSlider, you shouldn't let ticks_Tick update mySurfaceSlider.Value (or for a few milliseconds after).